# OpenTok event Typescript typing

Tags: typescript, opentok

Im trying to implement chat through [OpenTok API](https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/web/text-chat/) using 'signal' events to publish/subscribe.

This is my event listener which works (the signal is received):

```
// Listen for signal CHAT_MESSAGE
sess.on('signal:CHAT_MESSAGE', event => {
 
  const message = event.data

  ...

})
```

Problem is that typescript doesn't recognize `event.data` as a valid property. The type comes from the Session class:

```
Session.signal: Event<'signal', Session> & {
    type?: string;
    data?: string;
    from: Connection;
};
```

I've tried picking the type from the Session class like

```
const message = event.data as Session['signal']
```

Typescript complains `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Event<string, any>'.` I suspect it's because TS doesn't recognize the event type correctly...

I then tried converting to 'unknown' first:

```
const signal = (event as unknown) as Session['signal']
const msg = signal.data
```

Now TS complains: `Property 'data' does not exist on type '(signal: { type?: string | undefined; data?: string | undefined; to?: Connection | undefined; }, callback: (error?: OTError | undefined) => void) => void'.ts(2339)`

I'm not sure why it doesn't think that `data` is a prop when at the same time seemingly it says that it is...

How can I fix this problem, preferably without disabling TS type checking?

Comment: You might find this article interesting https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `Session['signal']` is a function:

```ts
signal(
    signal: { type?: string, data?: string, to?: Connection },
    callback: (error?: OTError) => void
): void;
```

And the type you probably need is coming from the `Session`'s class ancestor `OTEventEmitter`:

```ts
export class Session extends OTEventEmitter<{
    ...
    signal: Event<'signal', Session> & {
      type?: string;
      data?: string;
      from: Connection;
    };
    ...
```

`OTEventEmitter.on` method typings:

```ts
class OTEventEmitter<EventMap> {
    on<EventName extends keyof EventMap>(
        eventName: EventName,
        callback: (event: EventMap[EventName]) => void,
        context?: object
    ): void;

    on(
        eventName: string,
        callback: (event: Event<string, any>) => void,
        context?: object
    ): void;
    ...
```

As you may notice when `Session` extends `OTEventEmitter` there is no `signal:CHAT_MESSAGE` in the `EventMap`. Only `signal`.

Thus if you want your `signal:CHAT_MESSAGE` to be treated as a `signal` event you should write it as:

```ts
sess.on('signal:CHAT_MESSAGE' as 'signal', event => {
    const message = event.data // no error
    // `event` has type
    // Event<'signal', Session> & {
    //     type?: string;
    //     data?: string;
    //     from: Connection;
    // }
    ...
```

This typecasting has no runtime artefacts. It's only purpose to ensure typescript that your `signal:CHAT_MESSAGE` event has the same structure as the `signal`'s one. Though as always with `as` keyword now you're responsible for that to be true.